# Getting a HTTP POST binary payload to a byte array in Scala

Tags: java, http, scala, post, protocol-buffers

I have a socket which will persist for long. Client will keep streaming data requests to my server app through the socket. Request is a POST with a binary payload which needs to be copied to a byte array which i need to use to get the protocol buffer class.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:80
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 423
Content-type: application/octet-stream

[PAYLOAD]

val out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
```

Any ideas ?

UPDATE - I got a temporary solution using a DEPRECATED java function - DataInputStream.readLine.

Can someone make this code better ?

```
val in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
var n:Int = 0
var size:Int=0
while (n==0) {
    var str=in.readLine
    if(str==""){
        n =1
    }else{
        val breaks=str.split(" ")
        if(breaks(0).equals("Content-Length:"))size=breaks(1).toInt
    }
}
var payload:Array[Byte]=new Array(size)
n=size-1
for(i <- 0 to n) payload(i)=in.readByte
```

Comment: Okay - I got a temporary solution using a DEPRECATED java function.

Comment: In your updated version, where does the `in.readLine` come from? I don't think it's a method of `DataInputStream`... Also do you need to support *Chunked* mode where there will be no *Content-Length*?

Comment: `val buffer = new Array[Byte](bufferSize); in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)` .  Look at the BufferedInputStream docs, and then use that instead.  Sorry for an incomplete answer (you want, not just an Array[Byte] from a stream, but also to handle the HTTP header), but that `for(i <- 0 to n) payload(i)=in.readByte` line needs to be exorcised.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is under your control and  canonical, you can parse it like this

```
    static String pattern="Content-Length: ";

private static boolean readContentLength(InputStream in,int current) throws IOException
{
    int k=in.read();
    char read=(char)k ;
    if(k==-1)
        throw new IOException("-1");
    if( read!=pattern.charAt(current))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(current==pattern.length()-1)
            return true;
        else
            return readContentLength(in,current+1);
    }
}

public static void main(String...args)throws Exception
{
    byte[] bs= ("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"+
            "Host: 127.0.0.1:80\r\n"+
            "Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n"+
            "Content-Length: 423\r\n"+
            "Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n").getBytes();

    InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(bs);

    while(readContentLength(is,0)==false)
    {

    }
    StringBuilder lengthSb=new StringBuilder();
    char c=(char) is.read();
    while('0'<=c&&c<='9')
    {
        lengthSb.append(c);
        c=(char)is.read();
    }
    int length=Integer.valueOf(lengthSb.toString());
    System.out.println(length);

}
```